# If checked keep list accordion open

Tags: jquery, accordion

I've made a little and very simple accordion for a menu. There's only one thing that I can't get to work.

In short: Normal state of the accordion is closed. I open one of the accordions and check a checkbox. Then the page refreshes and the accordion goes back to the closed state. So i need to check if there's is **any** checkbox checked and then "re-open" it again by default.

So what I have is this:

HTML

```
<ul id="accordion">
  <li class="active">
     <ul style="display: block;">
        <li class="filter-item clearfix">
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="20883" name="filter[]" id="filter_20883">
          <label for="filter_20883"><span></span>H0</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 <ul id="accordion">
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><span>Strom</span><span class="close-open"></span></a>
    <ul style="display: block;">
      <li class="filter-item clearfix">
         <input type="checkbox" value="20887" name="filter[]" id="filter_20887">
         <label for="filter_20887"><span></span>Wechselstrom</label>
      </li>
      <li class="filter-item clearfix">
         <input type="checkbox" value="20888" name="filter[]" id="filter_20888">
         <label for="filter_20888"><span></span>Gleichstrom</label>
       </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#accordion > li > a').click(function() {

      var checkElement = $(this).next();

      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
      }

      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      }

      if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    });
```

Does anyone have a solution? Or is this the wrong approach to do this?

Comment: You have to use some kind of persistent data client side as cookie/local or session storage

Comment: I don't get why you have two uls with the same ID...